# Change async option for jQuery in mediawiki

Tags: jquery, mediawiki

I have a jQuery:
`$('#gather-facts').html('<script type="text/javascript">function gatherFacts() { var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); r.open("GET", "https://<server>/apps/merge?host=" + (document.title).slice(18,-9), false); r.send(); }; window.onload = gatherFacts;</script>');');`
in my MediaWiki:Common.js which is working fine except for that I need to run the script in synchronous mode.

There is a async option for jQuery but I can't seem to figure out how to add it to the above.

Currently using MediaWiki 1.25.2

Comment: I think you need to have a look at this link: [What is the X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: NOW you added the missing information!!! so you ARE executing AJAX. Please show exactly what a bunch of stuff is doing so we can help you. I am very close to closing this question as a duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: So true, updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the code is

```
$('#gather-facts').html('<script type="text/javascript">function gatherFacts() { var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); r.open("GET", "https://<server>/apps/merge?host=" + (document.title).slice(18,-9), false); r.send(); }; window.onload = gatherFacts;</script>');');`
```

Assuming the origin is the same as the page you are on, you want this instead

```
$(function() {
  $('#gather-facts').load("/apps/merge?host=" + 
    document.title.slice(18,-9));
});
```

Comment: It's in HTML, meaning: <script type="text/javascript">do bunch of stuff</script>, I've updated my question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yeah, but that would still make jquery run in async

Comment: There is nothing synchronous or asynchronous about your question so far. If you have `.load()`, `.get()` or `$.ajax()` then you may have some async/sync issues, but so far you have shown no such code

Comment: Is `function stuff()  { return "a bunch of stuff"; }
$("#id").html(stuff());` what is called a callback?

Comment: No. Not at all. It is a function that returns stuff. A callback is something you execute after an async call which I still think you are confused about

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100743/discussion-between-corex-cain-and-mplungjan).